# Pipe not found in custom component - Ionic 3 (Lazy Loading)

Tags: angular, pipe, components, ionic3

In my ionic 3 project I have my pipes wrapped in a pipes.module.ts and importing it in @NgModule for all my lazy loaded pages - works fine without issues.

However using the same approach in my custom component, using pipe inside the component template results in an error:

```
 Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'min2duration' could not be found
```

I tried also importing the pipe individualy in my component's .module.ts , but still same issue. The only way i made it work was to import the pipe in my components .ts file , wrap it in a function and us this function   like this:

```
import { Min2duration  } from '../../pipes/dates/min2duration';
...

@Component({ ... })
class CustomComponent {
  constructor(){ ... }

  min2duration(val){
    var m2d = new Min2duration();
    return m2d.transform(val)
  }
}
```

and in template

```
<span>{{ min2duration(duration) }}</span>
```

This way it works, but it doesn't feel like a proper solution, especially as i am using more pipes and more custom components in my project.

Is there a way to make the pipe work also inside a custom component's template like this?

```
<span> {{ duration | min2duration }}</span>
```

**Edit:**

pipes.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Pipes
import { DayMonth } from './dates/day-month'
import { Weekday  } from './dates/weekday';
import { Min2duration  } from './dates/min2duration';
import { HighlightPipe } from './highlight/highlight';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DayMonth,
    Weekday,
    HighlightPipe,
    Min2duration
  ],
  imports: [ ],
  exports: [
    DayMonth,Weekday,HighlightPipe,Min2duration 
  ]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

Comment: Can you share your pipes.module.ts code?

Comment: I've added it in the edit

Comment: It seems you declared and exported your pipes. So, it should work just fine. Did you import PipesModule inside NgModule where your custom component is declared?

Comment: Yes, in my custom module imports i have PipesModule. I use the same approach for pages and there the pipes work just fine. I'm getting the error only when i try to use it inside the component's template

Comment: Where do you declare your custom component? Do you have a custom module?

Comment: oh snap, now you've pointed me to the right direction.. I was importing it in the .module.ts of the component, but not the NgModule of the page it was using the component!  this resolves the issue.. Thanks for your help - if you like please post an answer with your suggestion, will gladly accept!

Comment: I'm glad, I was able to help. I posted my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import your pipes.module inside your custom NgModule where your custom component is declared.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bunyamin, much appreciated.  I was importing my PipesModule in the NgModule of the actual component, but not the NgModule of the page where the component was used.